# Stock notes are overlapping on StockChart, Is there any way to handle this?

Tags: highcharts, angular6

I am using HighStock in angularjs code for months now and it works properly. Now awe are migrating our app to Angular 6 everything works fine but notes/flags appearing on same date overlaps each other.  In Angular we had worked around for this issue using following method.

http://jsfiddle.net/p037jdyj/

But i am not able to understand, how i can use this in Angular 6

I tries to set stackOption but it didnt worked.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        lineWidth: 1
    },
    flags: {
        stackDistance: 50
    }
},
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check `highcharts-angular` [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper) on how to create your own wrappers. I'm not sure if you're using `highcharts-angular` wrapper, but it is recommended and can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. Check angular demo with your example posted below.

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/p78l1lnkmx

**API reference:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper